# Tagging or Censoring fields with Sequelize.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a good way of "tagging" or "censoring" sets of properties in a Sequelize model?

I mean something like the tagging supported by [nodejs-model](https://github.com/asaf/nodejs-model).

For example, my User Schema has a password field. I don't want this to be returned from any API calls EVER. I also don't want to have to censor this in the User Controller as it seems to be bad practice to configure censors on a per-route basis.

I would love to be able to do something like `User.find({query}, {tag: 'public')`

Answer (score 1):

I usually define my own helper methods to restrict the data returned by sequelize.

```
var User = connection.define( 'User', {
  email: Sequelize.VARCHAR( 255 ),
  password: Sequelize.VARCHAR( 255 ), //note: do NOT store plaintext passwords
}, {
  instanceMethods: {
    sanitize: function(){
      var data = this.get()
      delete data.password
      return data
     }
  },
  classMethods: {
    get: function( options ){
      return this.find( options ).then( function( record ){
        return record.sanitize()
      })
    },
    getAll: function( options ){
      return this.findAll( options ).then( function( records ){
        return records.map( function( record ){
          return record.sanitize()
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

If you want to generically restrict simple access to a field, this is also doable:

```
var User = connection.define( 'User', {
  email: Sequelize.VARCHAR( 255 ),
  password: {
    type: Sequelize.VARCHAR( 255 ), //note: do NOT store plaintext passwords
    get: function(){
      return null
    },
    set: function( value ){
      this.setDataValue( 'password', value )
    }
})
```

Please note that both of these methods leave the `password` field accessible through `user.getDataValue( 'password' )`.

So in your controllers, instead of using something like this:

```
app.get( '/admin-user', function( req, res ){
  User.find( 1 ).then( function( user ){
    res.json( user.get() )
  })
})
```

use this

```
app.get( '/admin-user', function( req, res ){
  User.get( 1 ).then( function( user ){
    res.json( user )
  })
})
```

or this

```
app.get( '/admin-user', function( req, res ){
  User.find( 1 ).then( function( user ){
    res.json( user.sanitize() )
  })
})
```

This won't stop you from **ever** returning sensitive data, but making all your routes use the same sanitation method will help.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I was hoping there was a more elegant common solution than wrapping sequelize find functions to remove sensitive fields. Nevertheless, your comment does help.

I'll probably try to write a mixin that wraps all the functions which return an instance of a sequelize model and removes sensitive fields unless the proper tag is found.